# What does the /tools directory contain in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I accidentally deleted the `/tools` directory in my Ubuntu 18.04 system. Is this something to worry about? What did it contain?

Comment: I was constructing a temporary system(Linux from Scratch) and had a symbolic link to it, instead of deleting the symbolic link, I ended up deleting the whole dir. So, I guess there was not anything important as such. But I am really not sure if Ubuntu had something important in it by default.

Comment: That sounds like a directory you created. What makes you think it came from Ubuntu?

Comment: Just like that. Probably it's just a symlink then

Comment: Shall I delete the question then?

Comment: Up to you :) If you are satisfied that it is indeed something you created, either delete or post an answer explaining that.

Comment: I will let it be here :) Might be of use to someone who comes out looking.

Answer (score 2):

It's not part of the default install, and apt-file is not helpful;

```
apt install -y apt-file && apt update && apt-file search /tools | wc -l
58302
```

So check your install log

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log ; zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*
```

or if you maintain an install.sh check that.

Comment: The install logs gives a lot of packages installed. How do I know which among them were residing in /tools.

Comment: Note that `apt-file search '/tools'` is going to find matches anywhere in the installed path - you'll get a very different answer (probably zero) if you match paths rooted at `/` i.e. `apt-file search -x '^/tools'` - AFAIK `/tools` is not part of the Linux FSH at all

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, it turns out that the `tools` directory is not a default directory and in my case was just a symbolic link.
The other answers on the other hand provide a reliable way to check packages installed(if any) just in case.